# Is there a CSS selector for derived HTML custom elements?

Tags: css-selectors, custom-element

Say there is a custom HTML element defined in the typical way, and another that inherits from it:

```
class CEParent extends HTMLElement { constructor() { super(); } }
class CEChild  extends CEParent    { constructor() { super(); } }
customElements.define("ce-parent", CEParent);
customElements.define("ce-child",  CEChild);
```

Now suppose the HTML contains only references to `<ce-child></ce-child>` elements. Is it possible to select / style `<ce-child>` in terms of `ce-parent`?

Like

```
ce-parent:and-derived-too {
    ...
}
```

?

Comment: No, CSS is for DOM elements, CSS has no notion of JavaScript Elements. You could maybe generate CSS based on ``this.constructor.name``?

Comment: @Danny '365CSI' Engelman: CSS can target and style custom elements just fine. The issue here is that it cannot distinguish between a custom element and a built-in one (like p or body), let alone a custom element that derives from a specific other custom element.

Comment: Yes, element X **extends** from Y with Javascript. CSS has no notion of element X 'parents'. So going up the prototype chain with JS and then dynamically creating CSS is an option

Answer (score 0):

This assigns parent Element names as CSS class on every element

Requires some string handling, because `constructor.name` is "" (empty string) for Anonymous functions

So Bono (U2) in the DOM is:

[image]

```html
<style>
  body       {font-size:1.2em            }
  .Homininae {background: lightgreen; display:block;clear:both  }
  .Hominini  {background:green;        }
  .Homo      {color: gold;             }
  *:after { content:attr(class); float:right}
</style>
<script>
  class Homininae extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      function proto(ref, chain = '', str = ref.toString()) {
        if (str.slice(0, 5) === "class")
          return proto(ref.__proto__, chain + " " + str.match(/class (\w*)/)[1]);
        else return chain;
      }
      let classes = proto(this.constructor.__proto__);
      this.className = classes;
      this.innerHTML = `<b>${this.innerHTML}</b> (${this.nodeName}) `;
    }
  }
  class Gorillini extends Homininae {};
  class Hominini  extends Homininae {};
  class Pan       extends Hominini {};
  class Homo      extends Hominini {};
  customElements.define('a-human'     , class extends Homo {});
  customElements.define('a-bonobo'    , class extends Pan {});
  customElements.define('a-chimpanzee', class extends Pan {});
  customElements.define('a-gorilla'   , class extends Gorillini {});
</script>

<a-human>Bono</a-human>
<a-bonobo>Kanzi</a-bonobo>
<a-chimpanzee>Ham the Astrochimp</a-chimpanzee>
<a-chimpanzee>Bonzo</a-chimpanzee>
<a-gorilla>Koko</a-gorilla>
```

[image]